# Magento: Show the Review Step in One Page Checkout

Tags: ajax, magento, prototypejs, checkout

I have not been able to figure this out for the life of me. I wanted to show the order review step(final step before processing the order) right away on the one page checkout in Magento. Any suggestions? Thanks all.

Comment: Do you still want the order review at the end of the checkout as well?

Comment: Well, I'd love for it to show up in the space it is designated to show. Instead of having to go through all the steps for it to show up it just shows up right when the one page checkout is loaded up. I know it is populated into the div #checkout-review-load. I can't seem to figure how which piece of JS code I need to call on page load to get it to show up though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of onepage.phtml, you will see

```
<?php if($this->getActiveStep()): ?>
   accordion.openSection('opc-<?php echo $this->getActiveStep() ?>');
<?php endif; ?>
```

which calls `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage::getActiveStep()` to determine which step to show first.  You can override this by creating your own onepage.phtml in your theme and changing the block above to be:

```
   accordion.openSection('opc-review');
```

However, the openSection function only executes if the target element ('opc-review') in this case, has a class of "allow" which is set by Magento's AJAX once the previous checkout steps are completed.  You could manually add the "allow" class using prototype, but once you get the step to display, you'll see that it is empty, since the AJAX hasn't populated the content based on the previous steps as the previous steps haven't happened yet!

So... You could create a new block based on Cart.php and insert that into onepage.phtml using `$this->getChildHtml('block-id')` and the layout xml.  You would need to insert it inside the `ol#checkoutSteps` as an `li#opc-summary.section allow` or something like that, and make the js change above to be `accordion.openSection('opc-summary');`

That's the best I can do at the moment for you. HTH,
JD

Comment: This was a huge help, got me going in the right direction. Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Pleased that it helped.  I've often thought that it would be a helpful thing to have, as long as it doesn't distract customers from completing the checkout!

Comment: @JonathanDay can you give some guidance on creating the block for the content to be loaded in review section too? When I tried what I am getting is whole html page which contains header footer, css, js all. I mean it replica of checkout page view source content?