# Magento checkout data persistence

Tags: magento, checkout

I am trying to preserve the user input from the onepage checkout. If the user refreshes the page it needs to be redirected to the review step and all the previous provided data should be restored. I managed to skip to the final step using instructions mentioned in this post [Magento: Show the Review Step in One Page Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916741/magento-show-the-review-step-in-one-page-checkout)
but however, there is no data loaded.

I tried finding where the checkout data is 'unset' but couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout data is stored as part of the request and not consistently added to one place. For instance, your checkout address information and shipping choices are saved to your quote, but payment information is not saved whatsoever. To do this well, you'll need to save all this request data to the session and add some JS around transitioning to the correct step.

For payment data, CC numbers will be a special case. Saving credit card information is almost always a violation of PCI compliance in the US (and may also be prohibited in other countries). If you integrate a payment wallet from an established gateway (like Authnet), or if you only use non-CC payment types with non-personal information, you may be safe here.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks, I think that the best approach would be to save the shipping and address info from the quote and return the client to the payment info. Any tips on restoring the first checkout steps?